# What is the Kinetic energy of two objects as viewed from their center of mass

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics

> A body of mass $m$ moving with velocity $v$ is approaching the second object of same mass but at rest. The kinetic energy of two object as viewed from their center of mass is:
>  (a)$mv^2$
> (b)$\frac 12 mv^2$
> (c)$\frac 14 mv^2$
> (d)$\frac 18 mv^2$

***Answer: (c)*** (that's what my book says)

i had oped (b) because their center of mass would move with same speed as the first object is moving and because of this if i were at the center of mass then i will see the first object at rest and the other object with speed $v$ and then the sum of the kinetic energy of these object will be $\frac 12 mv^2$

Comment: The center of mass moves half as fast as the first object, since it begins between the two objects!

Comment: Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The velocity of center mass is as follows(for two particle system in straight line) as per the question,
$$
v_c=\frac{m(0)+m(v)}{m+m}
$$
Now find the kinetic energy,